# How do I create 2 column layout with topnav and sticky footer with full height background-color

Tags: html, css, responsive

Is it possible to create a simple 2 column web page responsive layout with full height background color and a sticky footer that sticks to the bottom of the browser unless the page content height exceeds the window height space?

The desired div layout would be

```
<div class=“header”>Logo</div>
<div class=“topnav”>Nav links</div>
    <div class=“side content”>Links</div>
    <div class=“main content”>Some content</div>
</div>
<div class=“footer”>footer</div>
```

I’ve tried sticky footer solution that works until I try to make the divs between the header and footer 100% height as they may have background-color and want it to extend to the footer start. But when I set the height=“100%” on the html, body and topnav (assuming header and footer are fixed heights) it pushes the topnav contents down below the sticky footer. BTW, the sticky footer uses css position:absolute and bottom:0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the min-height with your sections which would help the section contain a fixed height unless the content increases. 
To make the two columns on the full height of the screen and enlarging with the increase of content, try something like this (css flex)

```
             <style>
                .main {
                      display:flex;
                      flex-direction: column;
                      background: /* Your Color or image */
                      min-height: 100vh; 
                     }
             </style>


             <div class="main">
                   <div class="sideone"> 
                          content
                   </div>
                   <div class="sidetwo"> 
                          content   
                   </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I couldn't get it to work as described but your highlight of the min-height did provide help for me. I have ditched the sticky footer with responsive layout and full height background-color'd side column as I can't get it to work. I am not suggesting it can't be done but the solutions others have posted are simplistic and don't seem to incorporate what I was looking for or they require jquery and get more complicated. I've returned to just having the footer at the bottom of all content that is not sticky.